# How to add string number value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have two variable. both have some value like.

```js
var position = "340px";
var end_position = "4px";
var final = position + end_position;
//result comes NAN 
// sometime it return 340px4px
// i want 344px
```

how do i add these value to get desirable result.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to remove x from string and use parseInt javascript function

Comment: There's many different ways to do that.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't store units along with the position value. It should be a unit-less number. Add unit just before actual usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more variation to do it using `Array.prototype.split`:

```js
var position = "340px"
var end_position = "4px"
var final = +position.split('px')[0] + +end_position.split('px')[0] + "px"

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`parseInt`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
var position = "340px";
var end_posiiton = "4px";
var final = parseInt(position, 10) + parseInt(end_position,10) + "px";
```

Comment: What is the additional parameter `10` for? Decimal system?

Comment: "radix - Optional. A number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt` (or `parseFloat` depends on number) and add both numbers

```js
var position = "340px";
var end_position = "4px";
var final = ( parseInt(position) + parseInt(end_position) ) + "px";

console.log( final )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're concatenating strings rather than adding numbers, to avoid that, you can remove anything different than a number *(i.e: using regex)* and then execute the add operation. Further, you need to convert the operands as numbers.

To convert the operands as numbers, you can use either the object **[`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)** or simply prefix them with `+`.

Prefixing with `+`

```js
var position = "340px";
var end_position = "4px";
var final = +position.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') + +end_position.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') + 'px';

console.log(final)
```

Using the object **[`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)**

```js
var position = "340px";
var end_position = "4px";
var final = Number(position.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')) + Number(end_position.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')) + 'px';

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the string to int, do the sum the convert them back to strings

```js
    var position = "340px";
    var end_position = "4px";
      var final = (parseInt(position) + parseInt(end_position)).toString()+"px";
console.log(final);
  //result comes NAN 
  // sometime it return 340px4px
  // i want 344px
```

Comment: technically, `toString()` is superfluous.